# I get this error when I try running summary on a model with "geeglm" class, but am not sure what I should check for

Tags: r

The error:
"Error: Can't convert `labels` <double[,1]> to match type of `x` . Cannot decrease dimensions."

I can't provide a reproducible example because the data is housed in a virtual server, and I don't know what are the properties causing this error. This is a model obtained from `geeglm()`, and this error happens when I use `summary()` on the model.

I've tried removing labels, coercing the data object to a data frame object, but the error persists.

Comment: Please include details of the call you made which resulted in the error. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure what a call is. Is it the commands I ran leading up to this error? If so, it was `model <- geeglm(..)`, then `summary(model)`.